# Android Studio - Cómo ocultar el teclado estando en un Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragment, activity, teclado

Al usar vistas de tipo "EditText", lo más probable es que al iniciar la aplicación el puntero caiga sobre el editText y abra el teclado, el cual yo oculto con el siguiente método (estando desde una actividad):

```
public void ocultar(){
        View vieww = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
        if(vieww != null){
            InputMethodManager input = 
(InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(vieww.getWindowToken(), 0);
        }
    }
```

El problema es que no puedo usar este mismo método desde un fragment. Agradezco de antemano por leer mi pregunta.!!

Answer (score 1):

Podes usar el `getActivity` para luego llamar al `getSystemService`, el codigo queda casi igual:

```
public void ocultar(){
  View vieww = getActivity().getCurrentFocus();
  if(vieww != null){
    //Aquí esta la magia
    InputMethodManager input = (InputMethodManager) (getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE));
    input.hideSoftInputFromWindow(vieww.getWindowToken(), 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Hermano, muchisimas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de ayudar a un desconocido. No puedo creer que al fin solucioné este problema. Realmente agradecido!

Comment: @TomasMenniti de nada :D Si se soluciono el problema marca la respuesta como correcta y me seguiran dando medallitas jaja felices fiestas.

Answer (score 0):

te agradezco inmensamente. Fue muy valiosa tu ayuda luego de todo un dia intentando la solucion, en todas las busquedas siempre se aplicaban a activitys y no a Fragments. Inexplicable tan pocas referidas a fragments y poco claras.

Gracias Dios Lo Bendiga.

Atte:
Jorge Jimenez
colombiaje@gmail.com